# C# Do not return an API response in run

Tags: c#, asp.net

I followed the steps in the following blog to create a link
https://techussain.com/how-to-create-a-zoom-meeting-link-with-zoom-api-using-asp-net-c-and-vb/

The API is called properly and the link is generated in debug mode but when you run the application the API do not return the link.

I am using ASP C#

Comment: Are you checked errors from request?

Comment: no can you please explain me how to do it

Comment: You can call `snapshot.hasError` in `StreamBuilder` and check error state or catch error in request future.

Comment: there is no error in snapshot.hasError as i replaced it with hasData i get `NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'document' was called on null. Reciever null'

Comment: Are you using valid table name?

Comment: table means collection name right ?

Comment: Yes. Collection name.